# How to get the counter variable value in for each scope in mule?

Tags: foreach, mule, counter

Is it possible to get the value for the 'counter' in the for each scope  ? I can see the values when debugging, I just want to pass it so I would be able to use it for another flow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried, looking the variable via flowVars expression?

```
#[flowVars['counter']]
```

Comment: I did tried to use that but Im still seeing null as the value. I have also tried #[flowVars.counter] as well as sessionVars. By the way, my for each scope is inside a Choice flow control. I have placed the logger after the choise since I cannot attach it after the for each scope.

Comment: I think im getting the value inside the for each scope but I can use it outside maybe because of the choice flow countrol

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get it by using SessionVars inside the for each scope. thanks for the help